# Bold some part of algorithm in overleaf, latex

Tags: algorithms, pseudocode

```
\begin{algorithm}
\FOR{$1\leq i \leq M$}
\WHILE{$x)>x_1$}
Hello world
\ENDWHILE
\STATE Set y=2  
\ENDFOR
```

Hello everyone, 
I have a question regarding the algorithm in the latex. I want to bold the text

> hello world

in the above algorithm. I want to italic the font of

> For

and

> While

and only

> hello world

should be bold. could any one help me? Thank you so much.

Comment: it would be helpful to give the complete MWE starting from `documentclass` and finishing at `enddocument`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For **Bold**

Simply enclose in braces and use command textbf

```
\textbf{Hello world}
```

[image]

For ***Italics***

Put the following line in the preamble for italics and bold  `For`

```
\renewcommand{\algorithmicfor}{\textit{\textbf{for}}}
```

Put the following line in the preamble for italics and bold  `While`

```
\renewcommand{\algorithmicwhile}{\textit{\textbf{while}}}
```